# i want to prevent user from input whenever they put 0 using regular expression (regexp)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using this code for html:

```
<input pattern="/^[1-9]\d*$/g" id="num-input" type="number" min ="0" class="form-control number" placeholder="Input numbers here" aria-label="Input number here" aria-describedby="btn-generate">
```

and this is in my script.js file:

```
function numIntoUnits() {
    let num = $('#num-input').val()
    // let full_name = $("#register-full-name").val()
    console.log(num)
}
```

it still shows the input numbers with zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex look overcomplicated. `/^[1-9]+$/` should do just fine.

Furthermore, setting `min` to 1 instead of 0 should suffice.